# How to force browers to store favorites in C:\Users\John\Favorites

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, bookmarks, opera

IE use C:\Users\Jhon\Favorites to store favorites of user named John. If other browsers use this folder in a similar manner, my favorites are sync across all installed browsers and there is no need for additional software. I guess Microsoft introduced this folder specifically for this purpose and wonder why other browser developers did not use it yet.

Is there any hack to config Firefox, Opera and Chrome to use C:\Users\John\Favorites to store favorites?

Comment: You're assuming IE, Firefox and Chrome all store Favorites in the same way. They don't. Perhaps you can have more luck with a synchronizer tool.

Comment: firefox has a bookmark.htm file that contains the bookmarks.  Firefox and IE have import tools but they run once at that is it.  There is no practical way that I know of to make this happen.

Comment: A programmer wrote code so Windows can mount a VHD file.  In much the same way a driver could be written to mount the bookmark.htm file to the c:\users\name\favorites folder.  However, this is a 100+ hour project by a specialist who knows how to write file system drivers.

Comment: Just use tools like this https://download.xmarks.com/download/all
Mounting files as folder require custom programming for each different browser implementation.

Comment: Such tools may be solution, but they are not hassle-free. Privacy issues, browsers compatibility, … .

Comment: While its possible to configure Firefox and Chrome to synchronize its favorites with IE, how the favorites are even stored are different across those browsers, which is the reason plugins like xmarks exist.